# I just started to learn Angular JS Framework and I get something extremely weird

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Singleton**

A singleton is a particular kind of class that, can be instantiated only once,
According to the angularJs Documents, Service and Factory are Singleton.

So if we define `app.service('b', fn)` like this

As per documents Angular JS call the Service like

`cache.b = new fn();`  so b’s stored value comes from newing fn.

So I can understand angular create instance itself so we cannot create new instance again so service is singleton.

But when define `app.factory(‘a’, fn)` like this, a's stored value comes from running fn.

Angular call `cache.a = fn();`

So there is not ‘new’ or oops concept. So where is comes here Object concept for instantiate and how is factory also singleton? Because of A singleton is a particular kind of class that, can be instantiated only once.

Will be Appreciate if answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, angular does instantiate a factory using

```
cache.a = fn();
```

but before this code it checks whether the cached variable is not an object.

Therefore, the complete code may be as follows

```
if (\\Check whether cache.a is not an object){
    cache.a = fn();
}
```

In factories, you instantiate a class and return the object, angularjs calls the factory function and caches the returned value somewhere. When you try to inject the factory somewhere every time, it checks whether the cached variable is not an object and if angularjs finds that the variable is not an object, it calls the factory function.

Comment: Ah! That's Good @Shridhar Sharma.  "When you try to inject the factory somewhere every time, it checks whether the cached variable is not an object and if angularjs finds that the variable is not an object, it calls the factory function."  Now i can understand. Thanks a lot.